# Can not inherit objective c class of NSMangedObject type in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, core-data

I have one parent class `base` which inherits `NSMangedObject`. (`base` class do not have entity associated with it. It includes only common properties and methods). I have multiple child classes in which few have entity associated and few are just using common methods in `base` class. And few child classes are in Obj-c and few are in swift language and all those extends `base` class.

My `base` is in obj c lang. `child1` class is in swift, when I initialize it and try to access properties inside it, it gives bad access error.

Then I created empty entity `test` and created sub classes in obj c and inherited in `child1` it gave the same error, but when I created sub class in swift and inherited it worked.

Is there any such limitation that subclass of NSMangedObject in obj c can not be inherited in swift?

**Edit**

Code -

Base.h file

```
@interface Base : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *property1;
@property (nonatomic,strong)  NSString *property2;

@end
```

Base.m file

```
@implementation Base 

@synthesize property1;
@synthesize property2;

@end
```

Child1.swift file

```
@objc class Child1: Base {

   var list = Child2()
   var array : [String] = []


   @objc static let sharedInstance: Child1 =  Child1()

   @objc class func filterSharedInstance()-> Child1{
       return Child1.sharedInstance;
   }


   @objc func loadData(_ completionBlock: CompletionBlock?) {
       if array.contains("Test"){
          return
       }
       // some code
    }

}
```

In some obj c class

```
Child1 *instance = [Child1 sharedInstance];
[instance loadData:nil];
```

After calling above function it gives error **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** for `if array.contains("Test"){` line as `array` is uninitialised.

When same did with Base class in Swift, it works.

Comment: Please show us your code. Core Data cuts corners, I wouldn't use (subclasses of) `NSMangedObject` without an entity.

Comment: `NSManagedObject` subclasses may be used in Swift. It's hard to tell what could be going wrong in your case without some relevant code.

Comment: @TomHarrington and @ Willeke Added code sample. Thanks for checking.

Answer (score 0):

The root problem is that `Child1` inherits from `NSManagedObject`, and you’re creating an instance like this:

```
@objc static let sharedInstance: Child1 =  Child1()
```

You can’t initialize managed objects like that, in Swift or in Objective C, because you’re not calling the `NSManagedObject` designated initializer. You should be getting error messages about that, although the app might not crash immediately. Even if it doesn’t crash, that object is not useful and will cause problems soon, such as the one you’re seeing. There are [two designated initializers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject), either of which is valid.

Creating a singleton shared instance of a managed object is a very unusual thing to do. It probably makes sense in some cases but I’ve never encountered that situation.

Comment: Please check out this question.. I have shared code. I used designated initializer but it still gives same error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47512840/nsmanagedobject-inheritance-issue?noredirect=1#comment81982384_47512840